# How to avoid async operation problems in Espresso?

Tags: asynchronous, android-espresso

I have a test case of Espresso where I check for with the first line whether the dialog is displayed or not

```
onView(withText(R.string.dialog_title)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

and them I perform a click on the button to close the dialog:

```
onView(withText(R.string.negative_button)).perform(click());
```

The thing is that the click operation always gets executed before check operation, because both operations are executed asynchronously. How to avoid of this problem and keep the order of the executed lines as it is written in the test case, when I don't need to perform the operations asynchronously?

Comment: I have never seen a case where onView operations `are executed asynchronously.` Check your premises, try to do a different action or put the full code but espresso is not async its too fast sometimes.

Comment: @satyajit If you would have a look at the implementation of check and perform methods you would see that those methods are queued to be executed in async way.

Comment: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/index.html "By default, Espresso waits for UI events in the current message queue to be handled and for default AsyncTasks to complete before it moves on to the next test operation". So, the test operations are not executed asynchronously. My advice: execute the test in debug mode with some breakpoints and check what is happening to your test.

Comment: You are completely right, but I assume execution complete doesn't mean all the UI components are loaded, therefore I think the IdlingResources are necessary. I solved the issue by extending an IdlingResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to customize an IdlingResource class which will wait for a certain condition until the View components will be loaded completely and only then continue the checks or perform the operations. Override isIdleNow method which should return true only when the view is loaded already (or some other condition that you need to satisfy).